# Creating Index Neo4j

Tags: indexing, neo4j, cypher

If I do the `CREATE INDEX FOR (var:TYPE) ON var.property` command in Cypher, does this apply to all current and future nodes of type `TYPE`? My assumption is that it does, as I never specify which nodes of type `TYPE` it applies to. So this means I'll only need to issue this command once, when setting up my database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, once you run the command
CREATE INDEX FOR (var:TYPE) ON var.property

For example:
CREATE INDEX FOR (var:Person) ON var.name

It will create an index on Person.name on current nodes and future nodes to come. So you only need it to run once.